# Non matching attribute 'INSTANT COLUMN(s)' between partition and table in mysql 8.0.20

Tags: mysql, partitioning, mysql-8.0

I am using MySQL 8.0.20. I found a solution that recommended to include `algorithm=Inplace` or `algorithm=copy` in `alter table exchange partition` statement explicitly, but my DDL statement doesn't seem to work, it gives a syntax error

```
alter table schema.tablename algorithm=INPLACE
EXCHANGE partition p20 with table schema.tablename_partition
```

Can someone point out what  I am doing wrong  here.

Comment: This isn't a syntax error; it appears to be telling you that the two tables' structures are different. Are they?

Comment: they are not.. created the partition table structure with "create table schema.tablename_partition like schema.tablename" , then dropped partitioning in partition table, just as mysql documentation suggested.